# Reduce map to string in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a map variable that I would like to reduce to a single string.

My variable looks like:

```
my_map = {
  key1 = "value1"
  key2 = "value2"
  key3 = "value3"
}
```

And I am hoping to reduce this to `key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3`.

Checking terraform documentation I could not find any function to reduce a map but probably I am missing something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list of the keys and another list of the values from the map by using the `keys` and `values` respectively.

You can then format those lists into a list of strings of those lists joined together by a colon by using the `formatlist` function.

And then finally you can get a single string of those elements of that list joined together by commas by using the `join` function.

```
variable "my_map" {
  default = {
    key1 = "value1"
    key2 = "value2"
    key3 = "value3"
  }
}

locals {
  my_list = formatlist("%s:%s", keys(var.my_map), values(var.my_map))
}

output "my_string" {
  value = join(",", local.my_list)
}
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for sharing. Same approach in one line: `join(",", formatlist("%s:%s", keys(var.my_map), values(var.my_map)))`

Comment: Yep, I just wanted to show the intermediate result so you go from map to list to string.